# What causes Express.js to log incoming HTTP requests?

Tags: express, logging

I'm integrating a logger on an Express app, and have replaced all `console.log` calls with our logger. Still stdout contains a line per request, and I can't find the place in our code that emits those.

```
1479433034910 INFO C:\work\Midburn\spark\app.js : Spark is starting...
1479433035437 INFO C:\work\Midburn\spark\app.js : Spark environment: NODE_ENV =
1479433035438 INFO C:\work\Midburn\spark\app.js : ------   Spark is running  ------
GET /he/home 302 24.940 ms - 84
1479433049833 INFO C:\work\Midburn\spark\routes\main_routes.js : /he/home
GET /he/login?r=/he/home 200 353.463 ms - 2454
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.857 ms - -
GET /images/flags/he.gif 304 1.039 ms - -
GET /images/flags/en.gif 304 0.486 ms - -
```

What is generating the lines that start with `GET`?

Comment: Post the middleware you set Express up with. Chances are if you used the "usual" Express middlewares you probably have `app.use(morgan('dev'));` in there.

Comment: @Randy indeed, morgan is the culprit - thanks! (post as an answer and I'll accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Express setup somewhere you likely have this line:

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
```

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan
>
> HTTP request logger middleware for node.js

Comment: Sweet. Already made the two play nice together: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28824464/11236