# How are you supposed to create Winston logger stream for Morgan in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, winston, morgan

What is the correct way to create a winston logger in TypeScript that will log the express Morgan middleware logging?  I found a number of JavaScript samples but have had trouble converting them over to TypeScript, because I get an error `Type '{ write: (message: string, encoding: any) => {}; logger: any; }' is not assignable to type '(options?: any) => ReadableStream'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'write' does not exist in type '(options?: any) => ReadableStream'.`

Here is my code:

```js
import { Logger, transports } from 'winston';

// http://tostring.it/2014/06/23/advanced-logging-with-nodejs/
// https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/node-logging-basics/

const logger = new Logger({
    transports: [
        new (transports.Console)({
            level: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true
        }),
        new (transports.File)({
            filename: 'debug.log', level: 'info',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            colorize: false
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false,
});



if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.debug('Logging initialized at debug level');
}



// [ts]
// Type '{ write: (message: string, encoding: any) => {}; logger: any; }' is not assignable to type '(options?: any) => ReadableStream'.
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'write' does not exist in type '(options?: any) => ReadableStream'.
logger.stream = {
    write: function (message: string, encoding: any) {
        logger.info(message);
    };
}


export default logger;
```

I have been able to work around this by adjusting my code to use `const winston = require('winston');` but would like to know how you are supposed to do this maintaining types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ultimately I ended up with this as a solution. I created a class with one method called write

```
export class LoggerStream {
    write(message: string) {
        logger.info(message.substring(0, message.lastIndexOf('\n')));
    }
}
```

then when adding to express I created an instance of the class:

```
 app.use(morgan('combined', { stream: new LoggerStream() }));
```

This works well for my situation

Answer (score 5):

`stream` is expected to be factory function that returns a a stream, not a stream itself.

A stream is expected to be a real readable stream, not an object that mimics it.

Since it is supposed to be writable as well, it should be a duplex:

```
logger.stream = (options?: any) => new stream.Duplex({
    write: function (message: string, encoding: any) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
});
```

This is a solution that is suggested by Winston TS types. I cannot confirm if it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it isn't quite working can you point me to where you found this information?  

I imported stream `import stream from 'stream';`
Then changed my code to match what you provided. I am getting `TypeError: stream.write is not a function
    at logRequest (C:\projects\node-service-starter\node_modules\morgan\index.js:130:14)`

Comment: I checked winston typings, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/winston/index.d.ts#L220 . There's always a possibility that types may be wrong. If you're sure that `logger.stream = {..}` works in your case, you can always turn down type checks and do `logger.stream = <any>{..}`

Comment: Ok... I found a solution - Here is what I ended up doing. I pulled in the split package and wrote my logger.stream as follows 

`logger.stream = split().on('data', function (message: string) {
    logger.info(message);
});`  

I found this info when figuring out how to remove the extra new line in the console. https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/70

Comment: I am starting to suspect there is something wrong with the typings though because when created a morgan.Options object then pass it to the morgan constructor you get an TS error. It sounds like with morgan 3 they will be bundling the typings. 

I have to add // @ts-ignore to this to get past the problems `// @ts-ignore
const morganOptions: morgan.Options = {
  stream: logger.stream
};

app.use(morgan('combined', morganOptions));`

Comment: Worked for me along with this blog https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/node-logging-basics/

Comment: @EstusFlask Is it possible to log req.body in logger.info(message); in stream?

Comment: @Rupesh I'm not sure I understood you correctly. Do you want to include req.body into a log automatically, while it's currently not included? This can be handled with Morgan formatting, it has access to req.

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask, Yeah I just did by creating custom token like this ```morgan.token('data', (req, res) => {
  return JSON.stringify(req.body)
})``` It's working perfectly fine.
Is it a correct way?

Comment: @Rupesh I meant this one, https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#using-a-custom-format-function . But yes, the way you did seems ok too to me.

Comment: Cool Thanks @EstusFlask!!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @estus who got me past where I was hung up. Here is the solution I ended up using:

```js
import { Logger, transports } from 'winston';
import stream from 'stream';
import split from 'split';

// http://tostring.it/2014/06/23/advanced-logging-with-nodejs/
// https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/node-logging-basics/

const logger = new Logger({
    transports: [
        new (transports.Console)({
            level: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true
        }),
        new (transports.File)({
            filename: 'debug.log', level: 'info',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            colorize: false
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false,
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    logger.debug('Logging initialized at debug level');
}

logger.stream = split().on('data', function (message: string) {
    logger.info(message);
});

export default logger;
```

Ultimately this issue got me to the final solution - https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/70

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TypeScript classes for logger, you can declare a stream() function that returns a StreamOptions type from morgan:

```
import { StreamOptions } from 'morgan';

//...rest of the class code

public stream(): StreamOptions {
return {
  write: (message: string): void => {
    this.info(message.trim());
  }
};
```

Then you can use this stream function inside express middleware:

```
app.use('combined', { stream: this.logger.stream()})
```