# Nodejs - TypeError: logger.info is not a function

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I am trying to combine `winston` and `morgan` in `logger.js` by Referencing
 [Node.js - logging / Use morgan and winston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27906551/node-js-logging-use-morgan-and-winston) .

But below Error occurs when I run the application.

```
/server/src/index.js:12

logger.info('Feathers application started on http://%s:%d', app.get('host'), port)

^


TypeError: logger.info is not a function

at Server.<anonymous> (/server/src/index.js:12:10)

at Server.emit (events.js:327:22)
```

App.js

```
...
const logger = require('./logger');
...
```

index.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
const logger = require('./logger');
const app = require('./app');
const port = app.get('port');
const server = app.listen(port);

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) =>
  logger.error('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', p, reason)
);

server.on('listening', () =>
  logger.info('Feathers application started on http://%s:%d', app.get('host'), port)
);
```

logger.js

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

// Configure the Winston logger. For the complete documentation see https://github.com/winstonjs/winston
const logger = createLogger({
  // To see more detailed errors, change this to 'debug'
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.splat(),
    format.simple()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'log-file.log' })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});

logger.stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding){
      logger.info(message);
  }
};

console.log(logger.stream)

module.exports = (require("morgan")("combined", { stream: logger.stream }));
```

**Updated the code according to comment.** 
No error now but no logging appear when I send http request by rest api.

```
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const compress = require('compression');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const logger = require('./logger');

const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');


const middleware = require('./middleware');
const services = require('./services');
const appHooks = require('./app.hooks');
const channels = require('./channels');

const authentication = require('./authentication');

const sequelize = require('./sequelize');

const app = express(feathers());

// Load app configuration
app.configure(configuration());
// Enable security, CORS, compression, favicon and body parsing
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: false
}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(compress());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')));
// Host the public folder
app.use('/', express.static(app.get('public')));

// Set up Plugins and providers
app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(socketio());

app.configure(sequelize);

// Configure other middleware (see `middleware/index.js`)
app.configure(middleware);
app.configure(authentication);
// Set up our services (see `services/index.js`)
app.configure(services);
// Set up event channels (see channels.js)
app.configure(channels);

// Configure a middleware for 404s and the error handler
app.use(express.notFound());

app.use(require("morgan")("combined", { stream: logger.stream }));  //added here

app.hooks(appHooks);

module.exports = app;
```

Logger.js

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');

// Configure the Winston logger. For the complete documentation see https://github.com/winstonjs/winston
const logger = createLogger({
  // To see more detailed errors, change this to 'debug'
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.splat(),
    format.simple()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'log-file.log' })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});

logger.stream = {
  write: function(message, encoding){
      logger.info(message);
  }
};

module.exports = logger
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting a Morgan instance (which is a middleware function), not a Winston logger instance. Therefore, the object that you get from `require('./logger')` is not a Logger, and it doesn't have an `.info()` method.

You should export a logger instead, and wrap it in Morgan only for passing to `app.use()`.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code but didn't work. Please check my update above

Comment: @ccc did you get any solution for this..?